# stuck appending image to dom

Tags: javascript, html, append

I am doing my first coding project and creating a meme generator with vanilla js and am stuck appending the inputted information as an image with text to the dom. here is what i have so far...can an image be inside the brackets for the function? i'm just stuck and would appreciate any input

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    h1 {text-align: center;}
    h2 {text-align: center;}
    p {text-align: center;}
    div {text-align: center;}
   
    </style>

<body>
    
   
    <h1>DANK MEME MAKER THINGY</h1>
    <form id="memeform">
       <p><h2>Top Text: <input id="topText" type="text" name="top"></h2>

       <h2></he>Bottom Text: <input id="bottomText" type="text" name="bottom"></h2>

        <h2>Image Link: <input id="imageLink" type="url" name="image"></h2>



        <div style="text-align:center">  
            <input id="Create Meme!" type="submit" value="Create Meme!"> 
        </div>  

        <div class="container">
            <img src="" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
            <div class="top-left">Top Left</div>
            <div class="top-right">Top Right</div>
            <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
            <div class="centered">Centered</div>
          </div>
       </p>
      </form>
    <script src="memeproject.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const form = document.querySelector("#memeform");
const topInput= document.querySelector('input[name="top"]');
const bottomInput= document.querySelector('input[name="bottom"]');
const imageInput= document.querySelector('input[name="image"]');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();

console.log(topInput.value, bottomInput.value, imageInput.value);
});

 function makeMeme(text,text,image){
const meme= document.createElement('img');
    meme.innertext= text;
   
 }
```

Comment: I can not understand what you want your 'meme maker' to do. What text do you want the user to type into topInput, bottomInput and imageInput? When they click on the 'Create Meme' button, what do you want to happen?

Comment: sorry for the lack of details, The assignment is to create a page that the user inputs topinput and bottominput(Text) and uploads an image into the third input. when submitted, the image should have the text displayed over it as a meme below, and you should be able to submit multiple times as well as delete the previous meme created

Comment: "For this assignment, you’ll be building a meme generator in the browser using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Your generator should consist of a form that accepts a link to an image, text for the top of the meme, and text for the bottom of the meme. When the user submits the form, use JavaScript to append to the DOM a div which contains the meme, including the image and its text."

Comment: Requirements

User should be able to submit a form on the page to generate a new meme on the page, and should be able to add multiple memes to the page by submitting the form multiple times.
Users should be able to click on a button to remove a meme from the page.
When the meme form is submitted, values in the form inputs should be cleared.

Comment: Thanks. That is clearer but I am not sure how to do it!

Comment: @user3425506 no worries, thanks for taking a look

Comment: For the input element which you use for the image (id='imageLink'), I think you should have type='file'. If you do that the browser will present a file explorer so the user can upload an image file. It is then possible to use javascript to display that image on the page when the form is submitted. Normally the file would be uploaded to a server when the form is submitted (ie. without the javascript).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I found this code and it seems like it might be part of the answer you are looking for. You can upload a file from your computer so it displays on the web page.

```js
var loadFile = function(event) {
    var image = document.getElementById('output');
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
```

```html
<input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="image" id="file"  onchange="loadFile(event)">
<label for="file" style="cursor: pointer;">Upload Image</label>
<img id="output" width="200" />
```

Now you need to find a way of generating the HTML to put the top and bottom input fields supplied by the user above and below the image.

The code here works by adding an event handler (ie. a function which in this case is assigned to a variable called loadFile) to the file input element so that when that element detects a change it fires the event handler. The event handler uses the event object. I did not know it before but clearly event.target.files is an array of files paths and so event.target.files[0] is the path to the file that the user selected. I hope that helps and also hope it is correct.